# I am receiving an invalid 'type' (list) of argument. How do I correct this code?

Tags: r, sapply

```
LumA<-data1[data1$id%in%First50,allgenes=='LumA']
Basal<-data1[data1$id%in%First50,allgenes=='Basal']
LumAgroups<-split(colnames(LumA),sample(1:3,ncol(LumA),replace=T))
Basalgroups<-split(colnames(LumA),sample(1:3,ncol(Basal),replace=T))
testA<-LumA[,colnames(LumA)%in%unlist(LumAgroups[])]
testB<-Basal[,colnames(Basal)%in%unlist(Basalgroups[])]
trainingA<-LumA[,!(colnames(LumA)%in%unlist(LumAgroups[]))]
trainingB<-Basal[,!(colnames(Basal)%in%unlist(Basalgroups[]))]
centroidA <- rowMeans(trainingA)
centroidB <- rowMeans(trainingB)
misclassifiedA <- sum(sapply(testA,function(x){sqrt(sum((x-centroidA)^2))- 
 sqrt(sum((x-centroidB)^2))>0 }))
```

Error in sum(sapply(testA, function(x) { : 
  invalid 'type' (list) of argument

How can I correct this?

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Try to say in words what you are doing.

Comment: Can you show output of `str(testA)`?

Comment: I have a data set that contains 20,000 genes and x number of samples that will be grouped as LumA or BasaI . I would like to split input dataset into 3 groups and use a test group vs the training group (n-fold cross validation. In addition, I would like to count the number of misclassified samples. Does this clarify things up, if not I can expand on this. I am new to this site so any tips would be helpful!

Comment: > str(testA)
'data.frame': 0 obs. of  0 variables

Comment: Which line is failing? Can you make the reproducible example that MrFlick asked for?